# Filter Ruby array of objects for any of multiple criteria?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

How can I filter a Ruby array for objects that meet any of several criteria?

For example, if I have an array of blog posts (each with a title, content, and zero or more tags), and I have a search term of "vacation", how do I return a list of all the posts with either the title, content, or tags containing the word "vacation"?

Obviously, the following would not work:

```
posts.select do |post|
  post.title.include? "vacation"
  post.content.include? "vacation"
  post.tags.include? "vacation"
end
```

Comment: do you know the `||` (OR) operator ?

Comment: If you can, use SQL, if you can't, use `post.title.include? "vacation" || post.content.include? "vacation" || post.tags.include? "vacation"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following

```
posts.select do |post|
  post.title.include? ("vacation") || post.content.include?("vacation") || post.tags
  .include?("vacation")
end
```

This makes use of the Ruby `||` operator.

Comment: Thanks! I only tried before without the parentheses, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following.

**Code**

```
def selected_posts(posts, arr, keyword)
  posts.select { |post| arr.reduce(false) { |present, m|
    present || post.send(m).include?(keyword) } }
end
```

**Example**

```
class Post
  attr_reader :title, :content, :tags
  def initialize(title, content, tags)
    @title   = title
    @content = content
    @tags    = tags
  end
end

posts = [Post.new("a", "b", "vacation"),
         Post.new("a", "b", "c"),
         Post.new("a", "vacation", "vacation")]

arr = [:title, :content, :tags]

selected_posts(posts, arr, "vacation")
  #=> [#<Post:0x007fc87a247da0 @title="a", @content="b", @tags="vacation">,
  #    #<Post:0x007fc87a247a80 @title="a", @content="vacation", @tags="vacation">]
```